# Move a struct through (void *) function argument back to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to send a struct through a function, taking (void *) as a singular argument, and then signing it to a struct of the same type (as in main/before function) inside the function. This results in error every single way I attempt to do it. Anyone knows how to do this?

```
struct a
{
   SDL_Surface *s;
};

struct b
{
   SDL_Window *window;
};

struct struct_of_structs
{
    struct a *struct_a;
    struct b *struct_b;
};

void loop(void *arg)
{
   struct_of_structs s_structs;
   // how do I assign arg to s_structs?
   s_structs = arg; // error
   s_structs = *arg; // error
   s_structs = &arg; // error
   *s_structs = arg; // error
   &s_structs = arg; // error
   *s_structs = *arg; // error
   *s_structs = &arg; // error
   &s_structs = *arg; // error
   &s_structs = &arg; // error
}

int main()
{
   struct struct_of_structs struct_struct;
   struct a a_struct;
   struct b b_struct;
   struct_struct.a = a_struct;
   struct_struct.b = b_struct;
   loop(&struct_struct);
}
```

Edit I have uploaded my original code at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HmWuRG2K). Whatever order of pointer or casting I add to the "arg" inside the loop, I get the error:

```
error: expected expression
        arguments = (*(loop_args*)arg);
error: use of undeclared identifier 'loop_args'
```

in every way I add the casting. Doing `struct loop_args arguments* = ((loop_args*)arg)` does not work, etc, etc. It always fails with "expected expression blah blah".

P.S. adding your solution to a random main.c using the dummy code worked and I learned something new, thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `struct_of_structs*  s_structs = (struct_of_structs*) arg;`

Comment: How come @Peter-ReinstateMonica? haha. I did take a course in combinatorics last year, lots of fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
s_structs = (*(struct_of_structs *)arg);
```

should do the trick.
basically what happens is you send a pointer to a struct but the function receives it as a void pointer, so to go from a void * to a struct you can't dereference a void *, so you cast the argument to a struct_of_structs pointer, and dereference it which will result in what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a pointer, not a new struct.

```
void loop(void *arg)
{
   struct_of_structs *ps_structs =0;
   // how do I assign arg to s_structs?
   ps_structs = (struct_of_structs *) arg; // error
}
```

Comment: That depends of what the OP wants to do with the struct in the function. Sometimes one wants a true copy (which wouldn't be a problem as long as `struct_of_structs` is a complete type, i.e. its definition is known; but one might want to deep-copy the pointer elements in it as well).

Comment: Yeah, but that's kind of advanced for a new C programmer.  You're right though,  you can create a copy if needed.

Comment: When I was a kid, you had to use memcpy to duplicate a struct you couldn't copy wit the equal sign.

Comment: Yeah, they come up with new things much too often. Next  thing you knew, they made sizeof() a run-time value for VLAs. At this pace we are due for another major change!

Comment: This works perfectly in dummy code but not in my actual code, can you check the pastebin I added? :) Thanks a lot by the way. I learned a lot from these answers!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of all the answers as well as the comments, I solved it!

```
struct_of_structs s_structs* = (struct struct_of_structs*)arg;
```

I cannot simply cast it to a struct of type "struct_of_structs", need to cast it to a type that is a struct aka "struct struct_of_structs"! Thanks everyone!